# how to get count of duplicate values of single column of MySQL along with distinct value of that column as key and count as value in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-optimization, subquery

how to get count of duplicate values of single column of MySQL along with distinct value of that column as key and count as value in Laravel using eloquent or raw query without exceeding from 1 or 2 queries.

the reason is that I am facing n + 1 query problem.

I have to get that column values as key and its duplicate count (e.g. value 1 occurs 3 times, value 2 occurs 9 times.)

Comment: can you please post your query here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.